# Convert a string to ASCII codes and back in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, string, ascii

In AS2 you had the functions `ord()` and `chr()` which specifically converted ASCII codes to their string equivalents.

However in AS3, `String.charCodeAt()` and `String.fromCharCode()` work with Unicode values.

Is there any way to convert a string character to its ASCII equivalent and back?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I found the answer, and its quite strange.

The usual so called "Unicode" functions appear to work with ASCII values as well.

```
trace(String.fromCharCode(65))  // "A"
trace(("A").charCodeAt(0))      // 65
```

Comment: the range of characters 32-127 is identical for both ASCII and Unicode. (even better, those unicode characters when encoded as UTF-8 end up having the exact same byte representation as their ASCII counterparts.)

Answer (score 1):

For the musical notation of sharp and flat use:

```
var flat:String = "♭"; 
trace( flat.charCodeAt() );         // output: 9837
trace( String.fromCharCode(9837) ); // output: ♭

var sharp:String = "♯"; 
trace( sharp.charCodeAt() );        // output: 9839
trace( String.fromCharCode(9839) ); // output: ♯
```

Answer (score 0):

weirdly the documentation says these methods work with Unicode but testing them I got the ASCII values. Maybe I miss something, but it looks fine for me.

```
var str:String = "A";
trace("ASCII dec: " + str.charCodeAt(0));
trace("ASCII hex: " + str.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));
trace("Character: " + String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(0)));
```

ASCII table:
http://www.sciencelobby.com/ascii-table/ascii-table.html

Rob