# Convert special characters (é) to normal (e)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

My application breaks because some strings that are given as an argument in a url for an httpservice-request contain special characters such as é. Is their a way to convert them to their normal variant (in this case e)?

Comment: Why not, instead, actually fix your application to accept those characters?

Comment: I do not know the answer, but I offer this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773578/convert-a-string-to-ascii-codes-and-back-in-flash - as a reference. Hopefully this will help others get an idea of how to change/support them.

Comment: Instead of trying to convert é to e, why not try to make your application capable of accepting é? You could switch encodings.

Comment: @minitech: it's the api that does not accept the characters, unfortunately I cannot change the characters myself because they come from outside the application.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function that would do it automaticaly for you. You'll have to replace everything one special character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [escape](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#escape%28%29) and [unescape](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#unescape%28%29) to safely post with your service.